# How can I denote abbreviations in Stack Exchange Markdown?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I'm interested in a way to denote abbreviations in Stack Exchange posts.

I've tried two kinds of ways. Python Markdown's [Abbreviations Extension](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/abbreviations.html) to no avail:

```
blah HTML blah

*[HTML]: Hyper Text Markup Language
```

and also via the [abbr HTML element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#abbr):no luck!

```
blah <abbr title="Hyper Text Markup Language">HTML</abbr> blah
```

Is there a way to do this in posts on Stack Exchange?

---

I converted this post from [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) to [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) after derp's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433/can-i-denote-abbreviations-in-stackexchange-markup?noredirect=1#comment82775_269433).

Comment: I think `abbr` support might be a very useful feature as Search Engine Optimization for questions and answers. Because users sometimes search things with full name, for example `Search Engine Optimization`, and sometimes with abbreviation, for example `SEO`. Using `abbr` would allow engines to find the question with any form.

Comment: @Tometzky well, I just hope Markdown is [Kept Simple, Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle "KISS").

Comment: I don't think this feature would make Markdown any more complicated - it's just one more allowed element with one allowed attribute. I'd say two lines to change.

Comment: @Tometzky no single change would make Markdown much more complicated. Still a considerable number of small single changes would make it more and more complex. Each 'considerable number of small single changes' would begin and progress with simple single changes, of which even this could be an example. What are the guards? Who is to tell what addition is OK and what is not? What for? I hope additions will be avoided as much as possible, so any further TheNextSimpleMarkupLanguageYetAgain will be unnecessary. An opinion is that sites' standards should rule search engines', and not vice versa.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I recommend finding a canonical resource and linking to it instead of using just a tooltip that spells out the abbreviation. The link can contain title text that users will see when they mouse over the link.

Example: [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)

> `[HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML "Hyper Text Markup Language")`

It's a little more work, but I think it's worth it to include a link if a user needs an acronym spelled out anyway.

Comment: But OTOH, just FYI and FWIW, some acronyms AAMOF would only have a "canonical" link in [UD](http://urbandictionary.com/) (but it would be ROFLOLMFAO-worthy to `abbr` this many acronyms, and probably most people ACGAF, and would mention that ASBMAETP, which AFAICT is EZ 'nuff).

Comment: @CamiloMartin *slow clap*

Comment: @CamiloMartin I had to look a couple of those up. I hope you're happy.

Comment: I need a translator to understand @CamiloMartin 's comment.

Comment: @DeMarco I'd be surprised if anyone doesn't.

Comment: 0-day exploit for exceeding the character limit on StackExchange comments: acronyms.

Comment: And even with the help of [UD](urbandictionary.com), you do not get the meaning of all the acronyms @CamiloMartin uses. [IGWNTFA](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433#comment82904_269436 "I guess we need this feature after all.")

Comment: @AlexEssilfie And another one: let's make links work even if someone forgets the `http://` prefix...

Comment: @bartoszkp: Hahaha! Pure oversight. I wonder how I missed it even though I had to edit the initial comment to insert a circular link. The fixation on the abbreviation maybe? Oh well #shrug#. To late to edit it now.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie I know ;) And that's why it would be nice if it worked anyway ;)

Answer (score 16):

Proposed amendment to [Bill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)'s [solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269436/124119) for when you want to just use an acronym and actually don't want to link to anywhere: link to this page. Example:

> [...] But [OTOH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433), just [FYI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433) and [FWIW](http://www.acronymfinder.com/FWIW.html), some acronyms [AAMOF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433) would only have a "canonical" link in [UD](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433) (but it would be [ROFLOLMFAO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433)-worthy to abbr this many acronyms, and probably most people [ACGAF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433), and would mention that [ASBMAETP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433), which [AFAICT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433) is [EZ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433) '[nuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433)).

It's very easy to specify them, too:

```
When I was in GitHub, I made a [PR] to fix the [API], and ...

  [PR]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433 "Public Relations"
  [API]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269433 "Academic Performance Index"
```

If you care about this feature,  annoying other people about it serves as a tried-and-true strategy to make other people give a sheet *of paper to someone who may write down an implementation sketch.*

Comment: This may be a workaround, but not a semantically appropriate use of hyperlinks.

Comment: @AndrewMedico It is a "Request For Comments on Meta"